# Backbone Collection wont render outside of fetch

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

#### The problem: My collection fails to render to the page if render method is called out side of a success callback when the collection is fetched.

I have a basic backbone collection that I'm trying to render to my app after it fetches some json from my server. After following a bunch of tutorials I'd expect it would work like this:

```
var restaurants = new RestaurantsCollection();
var restaurantsView = new RestaurantsView({collection: restaurants});
restaurants.fetch():
$(curate.targets.restaurantApp).append(restaurantsView.render().el);
```

The collection successfully fetches the json but its never appended to the page.

Alternatively, if I append in the success callback of `fetch()` it appends to to page fine. Like so:

```
var restaurants = new RestaurantsCollection();
var restaurantsView = new RestaurantsView({collection: restaurants});
restaurants.fetch({
    success: function(collection){
        console.log(collection);
        $(curate.targets.restaurantApp).append(restaurantsView.render().$el);


    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(errorThrown);
        console.log(jqXHR);
    }
});
```

RestaurantsView:

```
var RestaurantsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $(curate.targets.restaurantList),
    initialize: function(){
      this.collection.fetch();
      this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render, this);
    },
    render: function(){
      this.addAll();
      return this;
    },
    addAll: function(){
      this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
    },
    addOne: function(RestaurantModel){
      var restaurantView = new RestaurantModelView({model: RestaurantModel});
      this.$el.append(restaurantView.render().el);
    }
});
```

Is it necessary to append the render and append the view in the success call back of `fetch()` or is there  a better way?

Comment: You need to use the callback because fetch is asynchronous. Alternatively you could bind the "add" event of your collection to your view

Comment: @Gohn67 I know fetch is asynchronous, but there must be a cleaner way to create my collections and render my views right? or is this the way

Comment: Where are you actually "rendering" the html? Also, I think "sync" is the better event to listen to. The event for "reset" is only fired when you call "reset()" - which I don't see in your code either. I'm looking at the source code in version 1.0.0.

Comment: @anAgent Your right, changing the event to `sync` let me render the collection on fetch, just like I was looking to do. Rest only worked with `this.collection.fetch({reset: true});`. If you update your answer with this, I'll accept it.

Comment: Great, glad to hear! I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to bind an event on your collection that triggers render on your view - like so:

This assumes the code inside of your **RestaurantsView** *initialize* function.

```
this.collection.on('change', this.render);
```

Also, the event you're looking for is going to be "**sync**" rather than "**reset**". Current source code in 1.0.0 for Backbone will fire a **sync** event after a fetch.

**NOTE:** If the server doesn't return any data, "sync" will not be triggered.

Comment: I'm using `this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render, this);` in my initializer function. Any other ideas on why that might not being calling render function after it's succeeded?

Comment: Additionally, the `'reset'` will only ever be triggered when you use `collection.fetch({reset: true});` .

Answer (score 0):

Fetch is getting data from you're server through ajax, you need a callback function after .fetch

Answer (score 0):

Try reordering the lines. Usually all the events to be callbacked are registered first before calling fetch.

```
initialize: function(){
  this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
  this.collection.fetch();
},
```